# Magento site keeps crashing inconsistently

Tags: magento, logfile, exception-logging

My magento site has started crashing. Recently while accessing the site mostly shows the following error message

```
There has been an error processing your request  
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

After refreshing the site several times the normal page is displayed again.

The error report written to `var/reports/<error log record numer>` begins as follows:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:82:"Category Products Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.";i:1;s:2099:"#0 /home/krishbal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(162): Mage::throwException('Category Produc...')
```

Has anybody stumbled upon this before?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please tell us what you already tried yourself to resolve the issue and what your concrete question is. There is an error log number mentioned in the error message. What do the error logs say concerning that number? (If you don't know where to find the error log, ask about that in the question).

Comment: I got the same error before also, at the time i didn't get solution to fix this error.... So  i just re installed it again but now i just want the solution... and about the error log no ! it's giving different error log no while refreshing...

Comment: The changing numbers are absolutely OK. You will find a file with the number as filename in the directory `var/reports/` in your Magento installation. This file contains further information about the error. If you let us know what is written in this file, we might be able to help you. Otherwise we cannot even guess.

Comment: The recent error login number i got is 783283926636. I got that error file in var/reports/78328392663.. Plz tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Great, now that you have that file, please let us know what is says. Do you see anything suspicious? You might search for words like `exception` or `error` :) You might consider letting us know its full contents. Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: (If it is too long, upload it somewhere ([Wikipdia: Pastebin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pastebin)) and post the URL here. Maybe Search/Replace your site's name out of it, if you don't want to disclose it.)

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:82:"Category Products Index process is working now. Please try run this process later.";i:1;s:2099:"#0 /home/krishbal/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(162): Mage::throwException('Category Produc...') This is the first line of the error.. But now the error log no changed to 1163586565760

Comment: Yes, the log number will change *every* time, even if the error is the same (have a look though if it is the same, that might help). I have edited your question to include the bit from the log that you gave us. That is basically everything I can do for you. You have some error messages to search on and **ask better questions**. I have never used Magento (and I won't learn it. That's your job). Feel free to ask the Stack Overflow community in this or another question. But make sure to provide enough information for other people to understand the situation and to show what you already found out.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with *@zpea*. Please provide the content of the report file and we can help. Also try to look into **`var/log/system.log`** and **`var/log/exception.log`** in your magento install folder.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the contents of `var/lock` folder and double check the permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,.. The file permission for that var/locks is already 777.. Any other solution..

Answer (score 0):

Process Name            ID      Code

Product Attributes      1       catalog_product_attribute

Product Prices          2       catalog_product_price

Catalog URL Rewrites    3       catalog_url

Product Flat Data       4       catalog_product_flat

Category Flat Data      5       catalog_category_flat

Category Products       6       catalog_category_product

Catalog Search Index    7       catalogsearch_stock

Stock Status            8       cataloginventory_stock

Tag Aggregation Data    9       tag_summary

for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {

$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);

$process->reindexAll();

}