# Magento site showing error

Tags: magento

I'm new to magento.  I have been developing a site for the last few months. The site is almost completed. I planned to launch it within a couple of days but now the problem is it's showing some error like

```
"There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 783283926636"
```

The error log number is changing accordingly. I searched a lot of communities but I didn't find the solution. I came to know that the file is coming from var/reports/783283926636. While I keep on refreshing the site does come back. Please tell me the solution for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/10141197/693207](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10141197/693207)

Answer (score 2):

Check permissions for var folder, they should be 777 to enable correct work of your store.

Answer (score 1):

Anthony, you need to check that file, it contains a more detailed explanation of the error. Magento does not show it on the web page, to prevent exposing vital information.

Answer (score 0):

in your public_html dir you got folder error

rename local.xml.sample to local.xml

then your error will be visible on frontend and you'll be able to see what's going on

- it can be anything

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. Navigate to the "errors" folder.
2. Change local.xml.sample to local.xml
3. You should now see a new list of crazy errors all over the Magento page - this is okay.
4. Open magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php and look for:

   protected $_options = array(

   'cache_dir' => 'null',
5. Change it to:

   protected $_options = array(

   'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
6. Save it.
7. Now the final step is to go create a tmp folder in the root Magento folder.
8. That's it.